# All messages sent to DLQ after unsuccessful read of a message

Tags: azure, servicebus

After an unsuccessful read from my Service Bus queue using MessageReceiver of a message, all of my messages are being sent to DLQ, instead of only the message with the unsuccessful read. In the portal, MaxDeliveryCount is set to 3 and no retryExponential is used for creating the MessageReceiver instance.

What is the difference between MaxDeliveryCount available in the portal for a queue and the RetryExponential used for reading a message? Are they the same thing or are used for different scenarios? Maybe my problem is related to that.

Comment: Please check for message expiry time (message TTL) and the setting to dead letter messages after message expiration on the queue. That could be the reason why messages are sent to DLQ.

Comment: The problem is not related to TTL since is set to 14 days from the portal and messages are created today.

Comment: Which method are you using to read messages from the bus. ReceiveAsync (int maxMessageCount); receives messages upto maxMessageCount at once...would be good if you post some snippet.

Comment: I am using ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan opearationTimeout). The thing is, my MaxDeliveryCount is set to 3 in the portal and I am trying to read a message and abort its read 3 times so the message is sent to DLQ, but all my messages are sent to DLQ not only that one. The reading process without completing it with CompleteAsync is set just for one message and not all of them.